# Fragment dentro de ViewPager não chama nenhum método

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tenho uma atividade (`MainActivity`) que contém um `PagerFragment` que possui um `ViewPager`. No pager eu tenho 4 tabs diferentes.

Dentro de cada tab eu possuo um `Fragment 1` que pode se substituir usando o `FragmentManager.replace()` e o adiciono à backStack (`addToBackStack()`)

Tudo funciona normalmente, mas eu notei um problema que eu não consegui achar em nenhum lugar:

Quando esse `Fragment 1` , dentro do `ViewPager`, chama o `replace(new Fragment2() ).addToBackStack(null)`, o meu fragment é substituído corretamente.

Porém, quando eu aperto o back button, `Fragment2` é destruído corretamente, mas o `Fragment1` que estava na `backstack`, não chama o seu `onCreateView`, ou `onResume`.

Outra coisa que eu notei, é que quando eu chamo o `replace`, o `onDestroy` do `Fragment1` não é chamado.

O que está errado?

**EDIT**

Conversando com o @Wakim, chegamos a conclusão de que estou substituindo os Fragments de forma errada:
No `onCreateView` do `Fragment1`:
`mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lists, container, false);`

E no `onClickListener` de um botão responsável pelo replace:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = mContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                        .replace(R.id.view_lists_fragment, new CreateListFragment())
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
```

O `R.id.view_lists_fragment` é o container do layout do meu `Fragment1`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:id="@+id/view_lists_fragment"
tools:context="com.kayan.letsapp.Fragments.ListsFragment"> 
.... 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: O que você chama de "fragmento pai"? O `Fragment` que hospeda o `ViewPager` ou o `Fragment` anterior dentro do `ViewPager`?

Comment: Pergunta editada, @Wakim

Comment: Kayan, está usando o `FragmentPagerAdapter` para fazer essa gerência ou está adicionando os `Fragments` por conta própria?

Comment: Estou usando o `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` pra retornar os 4 Fragmentos diferentes nas tabs.
E aí cada Fragmento faz suas transactions, via `replace`...
Estou dando uma olhada nesse projeto agora:
https://github.com/danilao/fragments-viewpager-example/blob/master/src/com/pineappslab/frcontainer/RootFragment.java
E parece que ele cria um RootFragment, acho que não estou substituindo os fragmentos corretamente dentro do view pager

Comment: Hmmm, acho que o problema esta nesse `replace`. O ideal é que não interfira na gerência que o `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` faz, pode ser que ele esteja se perdendo... O que você quer é trocar um determinado `Fragment` dentro de uma posição por outro e depois poder voltar?

Comment: Isso, só que ao voltar, o Fragment que estava antes deveria chamar o onResume, ou o onCreate, pra eu poder atualizar certas coisas. Preciso que pelo menos alguma coisa seja chamada pelo `Fragment1`!

Comment: Consegue ver se o `onDestroyView` e o `onCreateView` estão sendo chamados? Por mim esses dois deveriam estar sendo chamados por causa do `replace` e do `backStack`.

Comment: `onDestroyView` não está sendo chamado, com certeza estou fazendo esse replace errado! Acho que estou usando o `id` errado!

Comment: @Wakim, Editei minha pergunta, se puder ajudar um amigo de eng. de computação da ufrj, eu seria eternamente grato ;D

Comment: Acho que isso está certo, mas só que você precisaria adicionar um `Fragment` dentro do `onCreateView` do `Fragment1` para poder ser removido. Acredito que você esteja fazendo isso certo (vou chama-lo de **RootFragment**)? Se for isso, no `onCreateView` do `Fragment1` você adicionaria o `RootFragment` no `view_lists_fragment` e depois faria o replace dele pelo `CreateListFragment`. Nesse caso quando você voltar, é o `onCreateView` e `onResume` do `RootFragment` que será chamado. O `Fragment1` sempre ficou visível/ativo então o ciclo de vida dele não é alterado.

Comment: @Wakim, Eu entendi, O correto então é ter um Fragment dummy que contenha Fragments, porque esse Fragment Dummy, por estar no ViewPager, não é destruído, certo?

Comment: Isso, exatamente. Dẽ uma olhada na resposta para ver se deixei isso claro hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo o código fonte do projeto, o que eu entendi que tem que ser feito é o seguinte:

## 1 - Criação do Fragment principal

`FragmentStatePagerAdapter` chama o `getItem`, logo você deve retornar o `Fragment` principal daquela posição, esse cara que chamo de `RootFragment` (Acredito que no seu caso seria o `Fragment1`, mas vou usar outra nomenclatura, seguindo o projeto que você citou).

O `RootFragment` adiciona o `Fragment1` que está inicialmente visível. O `Fragment1` é o filho inicial.

Acho que seria até melhor usar o `getChildFragmentManager`, mas não sei se é necessário.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.root_fragment, container, false);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.root_frame, new Fragment1());
    transaction.commit();

    return view;
}
```

## 2 - Replace do `Fragment1` pelo `CreateListFragment`.

Delegaria ao `RootFragment` essa responsabilidade:

```
public void replaceFragment() {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    transaction.replace(R.id.root_frame, new CreateListFragment());
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    transaction.commit();
}
```

No final você teria algo como:

> FragmentStatePagerAdapter -> add RootFragment
>
> RootFragment -> add Fragment1
>
> RootFragment -> replace Fragment1 to CreateListFragment

## 3 - Remoção do CreateListFragment

Quando você fizer `FragmentManager.popBackStack()` o `CreateListFragment` será destruído (`onDestroView` e `onDestroy` será chamado).

E o `Fragment1` será restaurado (`onResume` e `onCreateView` será chamado).

**Lembrando que não tenho tanta certeza do funcionamento disso, porque nunca tive que implementar algo assim. Mas acho que deve funcionar**

Comment: Vou implementar isso aqui e já digo, de qualquer forma já foi de uma ajuda absurda! Obrigado mesmo!

Comment: Estranho... Mesmo sendo sem o `onChildFragmentManager()`, quando aperto o back, ele destrói a atividade que possui o `ViewPager`, mesmo colocando na backStack

Comment: Em que momento? Depois de adicionar o `CreateListFragment`?

Comment: Sim, o mais estranho é isso aqui:
Mudando o FragmentManager na hora de inicializar meu adapter, o código funciona!
`AdminPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());`
Sabe me explicar o porquê? Está funcionando, mas pra mim o ViewPager deveria ter um ChildFragmentManager, já que são nested fragments, certo? Agora embolou tudo!

Comment: sobre a sua pergunta, ele adiciona corretamente o `CreateListFragment`, mas quando aperto back, ele destrói o `Fragment` que contém o `ViewPager` inteiro.

Comment: Não, o `AdminPagerAdapter` precisa ter o `getFragmentManager` e não o `getChildFragmentManager`. O conceito de `nested Fragments` só se aplica ao `RootFragment` e não ao `ViewPager`. Acho então que o melhor é o usar o `FragmentManager` nos dois casos, porque pelo que estou entendendo o `BackStack` não é "compartilhado" e quando você aperta o **Back Button**, ele verifica apenas o `BackStack` do `FragmentManager` de mais alto nível e não dos `FragmentManager's` dos filhos.

Comment: Ultima pergunta: Em que situação faria sentido o `ViewPagerAdapter` usar o `ChildFragmentAdapter`?

Comment: Acho que talvez, se você tivesse a seguinte situação: `Activity -> Fragment -> ViewPager (Fragment's)`. Nunca usei de fato esse `FragmentManager`, mas acho que isso seria um caso.

Comment: Pior que eu acho que é exatamente a minha situação, mas está funcionando perfeitamente agora! Muito Obrigado, @Wakin!